# BlackBerry browser caching even with no-cache meta tags

Tags: caching, browser, blackberry

Okay so, firstly this is a website where the user sees a list of tasks which are uncomplete.  It should work so the user clicks a complete button and then the item no longer shows, it seems not though!

When they click the 'complete' for an item I have onclick function executes a SQL update statement and then does a response.redirect back to that page, the sql statement executes correctly, the page does redirect BUT the list item is still there!

If the user then exits the page and comes back to it the list item HAS disappeared, this makes me think that the page is caching, however I have put the following in place to stop this:

`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" />`
`<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />`

`<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />`

which is fine on my BlackBerry Bold running OS 5.0, but does not work for customers with BlackBerry Bold running OS 4.x

Any ideas of what this could be are most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <title>Expires Example Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello World!
  </body>
</html>
```

This is from the Blackberry support forum:  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/Browser-cache-and-quot-Back-quot-button/m-p/155986

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately I have already tried that and it didn't work either, really hit a brick wall with this one

Answer (score 0):

How about this
http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/documentation/rim_cache_element_1264486_11.html

try changing disableAllCache to false in the config.xml

```
<rim:cache disableAllCache=["true" | "false"]
           aggressiveCacheAge="time"
           maxCacheSizeTotal="size"
           maxCacheSizeItem ="size" />
```